# Canvas game move sprite

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm creating a small game and I'm trying to make my Enemy sprite bounce randomly off the canvas walls (change direction and fly off randomly when it hits the walls / edge of canvas)
example - [http://www.onlywebpro.com/2011/07/20/html5-canvas-for-absolute-beginners-part-4/]

Here is my function that moves the enemy , but unfortunately it does not work, the enemy fly off the edge of the canvas, can someone help?

```
Enemy.prototype.update = function () {

    this.drawX = this.drawX +5 ;
    this.drawY = this.drawY+ 5;

if ((this.x + 2) >= canvasWidth || (this.x - 2) <= 0) 
{    
this.x = -2;   
}

  if ((this.y + 2) >= canvasHeight || (this.y - 2) <= 0) { 
        this.y = -2;
      }
     }
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want the object to change the direction, you don't just need to change the position, you need to change its current movement vector. Currently your movement vector is hardcoded as `+5` and `+ 5` in lines 3 and 4.

Move your movement vector to variables which you set in the constructor of the object:

```
this.moveX = 5;
this.moveY = 5;
```

then change your position per frame by that variables instead of a hardcoded value:

```
this.x = this.x + this.moveX ;
this.y = this.y + this.moveY ;
```

When you detect a horizontal or vertical collision, invert the corresponding movement vector:

```
if ((this.x + 2) >= canvasWidth || (this.x - 2) <= 0) 
{    
    this.moveX = -this.moveX;   
}

if ((this.y + 2) >= canvasHeight || (this.y - 2) <= 0) { 
    this.moveY = -this.moveY;
}
```